# How to change gridView custom item image

Tags: android, gridview, layout, view, keyboard

hi i have gridview which shows keyboard characters

how can i declear a  method that  change clicked item image

for example when user clicked on  "D"  the img of "D" be disappear and replace with  a gray img ?

if its possible show me an example

thank u

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
//        return mThumbIds.length;
  return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textview;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
//textview = new TextView(mContext);
//textview.setLayoutParams(new  GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//textview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
//
//          
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        } else {
     imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
//          textview = (TextView) convertView;
        }


    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        //textview.setText(alphabet[position]);
      return imageView;
  //  return textview;
    }

    // references to our images

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.al0, R.drawable.al1,
            R.drawable.al2, R.drawable.al3,
            R.drawable.al4, R.drawable.al5,
            R.drawable.al6, R.drawable.al7,
            R.drawable.al8, R.drawable.al9,
            R.drawable.al10, R.drawable.al11,
            R.drawable.al12, R.drawable.al13,
            R.drawable.al14, R.drawable.al15,
            R.drawable.al16, R.drawable.al17,
            R.drawable.al18, R.drawable.al19,
            R.drawable.al20, R.drawable.al21,
            R.drawable.al22, R.drawable.al23,
            R.drawable.al24, R.drawable.al25,
            R.drawable.al26, R.drawable.al27,
            R.drawable.al28, R.drawable.al29,
            R.drawable.al30, R.drawable.al31,
            R.drawable.al32
    };


}
```

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_game_layout);

        GridView gridview= (GridView)  findViewById(R.id.gridView2);


        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                ImageView imageshow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageshow.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);



            }
            });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.al0, R.drawable.al1,
            R.drawable.al2, R.drawable.al3,
            R.drawable.al4, R.drawable.al5,
            R.drawable.al6, R.drawable.al7,
            R.drawable.al8, R.drawable.al9,
            R.drawable.al10, R.drawable.al11,
            R.drawable.al12, R.drawable.al13,
            R.drawable.al14, R.drawable.al15,
            R.drawable.al16, R.drawable.al17,
            R.drawable.al18, R.drawable.al19,
            R.drawable.al20, R.drawable.al21,
            R.drawable.al22, R.drawable.al23,
            R.drawable.al24, R.drawable.al25,
            R.drawable.al26, R.drawable.al27,
            R.drawable.al28, R.drawable.al29,
            R.drawable.al30, R.drawable.al31,
            R.drawable.al32
    };

    private Integer[] mThumbIds1 = {
            R.drawable.al32,R.drawable.al32,
            R.drawable.al32,R.drawable.al32,
            R.drawable.al32,R.drawable.al32
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { ... }
```

A quick&Dirty way is to use the parameter **View v**, it's the view of the object that you have clicked on. On this view you can try to change the imageDrawable or backgound:

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button );
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE );
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
v.setImageDrawable(myIcon);
```

Probably you must manage when click on another image to revert this image change, this is just a startup idea, hope this help!

Comment: tank u  it seems good idea but v.setimagDrawable dosent work  can u  give me a better way ?

Comment: The error? you view in gridView is a image or a container for the image? if is an Image, try to cast v in this way: **((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(myIcon)**

Comment: done .   i have another problem  should ask it in new topic ?

Answer (score 0):

In your **onItemClick()** method, the second parameter **View v** is actually the view that was clicked. So if that is just an **ImageView**, then you cast that argument to **ImageView** and you can set new image. Simply as:

```
ImageView newImage = (ImageView)v;
newImage.setImageResource(put_some_image_id_here);
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer but the image view in mainActivity is not the image view that gridview  uses